# Unable to find given string element and its index from an ArrayList using java

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

I need to get an index of a given element in one ArrayList.Then I need to get the index value of another ArrayList. But I am not able to get the searching string element even though ArrayList has the element within it.
Array List Values:

issn_valueLst_backup1=[10.1111/ejed.ila_test, 10.1111/ejed.12141, 10.1111/ejed.12143, 10.1111/ejed.12170, 10.1111/ejed.12171, 10.1111/ejed.12173, 10.1111/ejed.12174, 10.1111/ejed.12175, 10.1111/ejed.12176, 10.1111/ejed.12177, 10.1111/ejed.12178]

doi_list_2=10.1111/ejed.ila_test 
code :

```
int index = issn_valueLst_backup1.indexOf(doi_list_2);
System.out.println("Found element_3 : " + (index == -1?false:true) + 
", in position : " + index);
String xml_filename_Found = Only_Filename_list.get(index);
System.out.println("File name finally:::"+xml_filename_Found);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and reformat it.

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: Define "i am not able" precisely. What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Also, please respect the Java naming conventions, and choose much better names for your variables. like for example `elements` instead of `issn_valueLst_backup1`, `fileNames` instead of `Only_Filename_list`, `xmlFileNameFound` instead of `xml_filename_Found`

Comment: And please, don't overwrite the edits I made with yours if yours don't fix the formatting better than mine do. There is a preview when editing. You shouldn't post until the preview looks perfect.

Comment: is it possible that `doi_list_2` may contain extra space or something? try `.indexOf(doi_list_2.trim());`

Comment: Sorry .Formatted again.

Comment: @yazan : Thank you,i got it and works fine now.